# fetch() with FormData

Tags: javascript, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

I am learning uploading files with Node.js and multer. I have configurated main app.js file, aswell as upload.html.

My form:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="/uploads" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="upload-input" type="file" name="uploads" multiple>
    <button class="upload-button" type="button">File</button>
</form>
```

and script.js with which I am trying to handle form data and posting it with fetch():

```
uploadInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    let files = event.target.files;

    if(files.length > 0) {
        let formData = new FormData();

        for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let file = files[i];

            formData.append('uploads', file);
        }

        fetch('uploads', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(res => res.json(), error => error.message);
    }
});
```

Files are uploading and everything is fine except two errors.
First displays at browser console:

```
uploader:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
```

And second in WebStorm IDE console:

```
(node:51729) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
```

Do you have an idea why it's throwing with errors, while everything works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with `.then(res => res.json(), error => error.message);`

The JSON parsing error is almost certainly because you're not getting JSON back in your response. It's hard to tell why exactly you're getting the deprecation warning, but it may be related to your `.then()` call. For both, do something useful with the result, such as `console.log(res)` and `console.log(error)`.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to deal with this JSON parsing error, how to omit it? Unlucky logging response and error did not solve the problem with deprecation warning.

Comment: If it's not JSON, you can't use `json()`. If it's a success message, you probably don't need to do anything with it at all.

Comment: I am sending uploaded with form-data files, what do you propose then instead of json()? :)

Comment: @veritimus yes, but this is where you're handling the response. The response coming back from the server does not appear to be JSON.